# Volume of $f(x)=\sin(x-1)$ rotating around the $y$-axis?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

> Given $f(x)=\sin{(x-1)}, [0, 1 + \frac{\pi}{2}]$, find the volume of revolution with respect to the $y$-axis, given the limits $y=0$, $y=1$, and $x=0$.

If I use the disk method to find the volume:
$\pi\int^{1}_{0}{(1+\arcsin{y})^2}dy$, the answer will be $\approx 8.19$.

However, if I do it using the shells method: $2\pi\int^{1+\frac{\pi}{2}}_{1} {x\sin(x-1)}dx$, the answer would be $4\pi \approx 12.6.$

> What's my mistake, or why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: sin is not one-to-one on that domain. so arcsin is the problem.

Comment: Oh I see! Which method is the one to go for? @DavidP

Comment: shell method. disk method will not work directly, you will need to find a function that represents the right-hand side of the region and then apply the "washer" method. too much work

Comment: Ah I see where this is going! Thanks a ton! @DavidP

Comment: wait, sorry, i had the wrong region in mind. the reason for the difference is that the region begins at the intersection of $x=0$ and $x=\arcsin(y)+1$. your integration bounds for the disk method should be $y=\sin(-1)$ to $y=1$. also your integrand for the shell method should be $x(1-\sin(x-1)) dx$

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the volumes of two **different** solids.

Consider $y=\sin x$ on $[0,\pi/2]$, and calculates the volume of the solid obtainded by rotating about the $y$-axis the region bounded by $x=0$, $y=1$ and the curve on $[0,\pi/2]$. Using your way to do the calculation, you would get
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}2\pi x\sin x\ dx=2\pi
$$
and 
$$\int_0^1\pi\arcsin^2 y\ dy=\frac{1}{4}\pi^3-2\pi
$$
But actually, 
$$
\color{blue}{\pi\cdot \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2\cdot 1-}\int_0^{\pi/2}2\pi x\sin x\ dx=\int_0^1\pi\arcsin^2 y\ dy=\frac{1}{4}\pi^3-2\pi
$$